# How do I make a selection to proceed to another function if I have completed the current function?

Tags: c++, function

Rather than ending the program right after the first function which is  "1", how do I make a choice to proceed to another function ? Something like making the menu appear again to make selection for other functions. Example: 2 or 3

```
#include <stdio.h>

int testing(); int rewarding(); int buying();

void main()
{
    int menu;

    printf("Enter 1 for testing:\n");
    printf("Enter 2 for rewarding:\n");
    printf("Enter 3 for buying:\n");
    scanf("%d", &menu);

    if (menu == 1) {       //first function
        testing();
    }

    else if (menu == 2) {    //second function
        rewarding();
    }

    else if (menu == 3) {    //third function
        buying();
    }

    system("pause");
}

testing() {
    printf("this is the first function\n"); // proceed to selection menu to choose another function when first function is completed
    return(0);
}

rewarding() {
    printf("this is the second function\n");
    return (0);
}

buying() {
    printf("this is the third function\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: @LogicStuff Sorry I am a newbie. Could you be more specific ? Or show the workings ?
Thanks

Comment: Please read up on how to use loops in C or C++.  There are countless examples out there, as it's one of the fundamental tools of procedural languages.

Comment: @paddy yes I have tried searching. But all of them came with "count" or "cin" etc, which are things that I don't understand as a newbie. Probably too complicated for me as a newbie ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your menu and function call stuff in a while(true) { ... } loop and make a 4th menu entry for 'quit' and the code else if (menu == 4) { break; }

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while(true)
    {
        int menu;
        std::cout << "Press (1) FuncA, (2) Func B, (3) Func C or (4) Quit" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> menu;
        if (menu == 1)
            testing();
        else if (menu == 2)
            rewarding();
        else if (menu == 3)
            buying();
        else if (menu == 4)
            break;
        else
            std::cout << "Please press 1, 2, 3 or 4" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The "break" statement immediatly cancels the while() loop and the application exits. All other choices execute the corresponding function and loop back to the menu.

Brackets around the call to testing(), rewarding() or buying() are used for grouping expressions and are not necessary if you only need one expression. I removed them from my ifs, but that's just a matter of taste.

You should also specify a return type for your functions. Use 
void testing() {}
if you do not need to return a value (you'd also have to remove the return statements from the functions)

Comment: You are right. I fixed that. That's what happens when you write code in Notepad.exe and do not even try to compile it ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `while` loop around the code that gets user input and does something with it.
2. Provide an option to exit the loop.

```
// Loop forever until the user chooses the option to exit the loop.
while ( true )
{
   printf("Enter 1 for testing:\n");
   printf("Enter 2 for rewarding:\n");
   printf("Enter 3 for buying:\n");
   printf("Enter 4 to exit:\n");

   if ( scanf("%d", &menu) != 1 )
   {
      // Error in input.
      // Read and discard the rest of the line.
      printf("Invalid input. Discarding the input.\n");
      int c;
      while ( (c = getc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n' );

      // Go on to the start of the loop.
      continue;
   }

   if (menu == 1) {       //first function
      testing();
   }

   else if (menu == 2) {    //second function
      rewarding();
   }

   else if (menu == 3) {    //third function
      buying();
   }
   else if (menu == 4) {    //fourth option
      break;
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("Invalid option: %d\n", menu);
   }
}
```

In addition to the above...

Change the return type of `main` from `void` to `int`. That is the standard compliant way of defining `main`.

```
int main() { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop. And `switch` is clearer than `if-else`.

Be careful about the return value of `scanf`, it might be `0`, `1` or `EOF`. We only want to proceed when it's `1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_menu() {
    printf("Enter 1 for testing:\n");
    printf("Enter 2 for rewarding:\n");
    printf("Enter 3 for buying:\n");
}

void testing() {}
void rewarding() {}
void buying() {}    

int main() {
    while (1) {

        print_menu();

        int menu;
        int ret = scanf("%d", &menu);

        if (ret == EOF) break;
        if (ret != 1) continue;

        switch(menu) {
        case 1: testing(); break;
        case 2: rewarding(); break;
        case 3: buying(); break;
        default: printf("Unknown input %d\n", menu); break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```